# Any satellites in Earth-Sun L3 point?

Tags: lagrangian-points

Do we (the humanity) have any satellites in the Sun-Earth $L_3$ point? If not, then what are the plans to put some ships into this point?

Comment: Do you mean the Earth Moon L3?

Comment: Considering that an [L3 point is *unstable*](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/8658/29), I seriously doubt it is being considered as a location for any long-term deployment. A spacecraft certainly could *pass through* it, though, on its way somewhere else, but I doubt that's what you have in mind.

Comment: Which L3 point are we talking about? ESL3? EML3? Until this is stated this question is unanswerable.

Comment: What's the advantage of an L3 (Earth-Sun) satellite?   Nasa set up a pair of satellites to get a 360 degree view of the sun a few years back.   http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/stereo/news/entire-sun.html

Comment: Small point to add.   A disadvantage to L3 is that it would often not be able to send messages to earth.    http://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/mission/observatory_l2.html   "NASA is unlikely to find any use for the L3 point since it remains hidden behind the Sun at all times."

Comment: related: [Why would Hollywood's Planet X (at earth's L3) be unstable?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13947/12102) and [Can L3 have halo orbits?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40864/12102) and [Do horseshoe orbits have anything to do with Lagrange points? Do words fail us here?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34871/12102)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR** No, there are no sats there today, and no declared plans from any of space agencies to do that.

Here's why:

An Earth-Sun $L_3$ point is an unfortunate place for a satellite to be in.

First off, it is unstable (thus without constant station-keeping burns an object placed there will fall out and start roaming about the Solar System). An alternative would be a [halo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_orbit) or [Lissajous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_orbit) orbit around $L_3$.

Second, the satellite would face significant difficulties in communicating via DSN. It would be permanently in [solar conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_conjunction) with the Earth, and as the Sun is a very strong source of radio noise, the signal would drown in the noise. Of course, one can use satellites placed in Earth-Sun $L_4$ or $L_5$ points as relays, but it would make the whole $L_3$ program much more costly and unreliable.

This leads us to the third point: what can be the mission **requiring** a halo/Lissajous orbit around $L_3$?

- Space telescope? Nah, there's nothing in the far space that can't be observed in the course of Earth's normal yearly travel around the Sun.
- Solar weather observations? Nope, by definition we are interested in solar events going **our** way, not in the opposite direction.
- There's only one speculative mission that forces us to have something in $L_3$: **watching out for an alien invasion**, 'cause an advanced spacefaring civilization would definitely want to reduce our reaction time and choose an approach obscured by the Sun. Even then, $L_4$ and $L_5$ points offer better link budgets and only slightly worse detection conditions. A smart alien invasion would seek to disrupt the early warning network by inducing a fault that could be attributed to natural causes.

To sum it up: an $L_3$ satellite is not worth it unless you believe in evil aliens wanting to invade the Earth.

EDIT: Following andy256's [suggestion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/any-satellites-in-earth-sun-l3-point#comment22279_8519), I quote the para from Tantardini et al. (2010) paper:

> A space observatory placed at or around L3 could provide insight into local astrophysical phenomena such as the solar wind and the properties of the Sun’s magnetosphere; it could monitor the evolution of the sunspots, perform solar storm forecast and observe the space environment from a new perspective, hidden to the Earth, and in this way supplement and complete the
>   information obtainable, e.g., from L1 or from Earth based observatories. A satellite at L3 could be even thought of as part of a circular or spherical constellation of s/c monitoring the Sun’s activity and the space environment at many different angles. Moreover, L3 may constitute a privileged site to perform relativity experiments, such as measuring the gravitational
>   bending of light on behalf of the Sun, as a follow-up of the Cassini–Huygens radio science observations. Finally, some minor bodies such as NEOs and comets, hidden by the Sun as viewed from Earth, could be observed and even tracked from this more favorable location.

Source: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10569-010-9299-x

Please note that I'm not convinced in the slightest by their arguments.

Comment: *"watching out for an alien invasion"*. Enough people do that already, here at home at L0.

Comment: So, you state that there is no satellites in L3 and no plans?

Comment: @Dims: none and none.

Comment: +1 for the aliens! Seriously, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point#Spaceflight_applications) suggests *A spacecraft orbiting near Sun–Earth L3 would be able to closely monitor the evolution of active sunspot regions before they rotate into a geoeffective position ...*

Comment: Wouldn't the satellite be in conjunction rather than in opposition?

Comment: @pericynthion - right you are, thanks. No more cider for me now, I'm afraid.

Comment: "… by definition we are interested in solar events going our way, not in the opposite direction." A short sighted definition in my opinion. Views from several angles would give us a better understanding of solar weather. Further, events on the other side influence solar weather on our side.

Comment: I agree with you HopDavid.   360 degree views of the sun is useful and we've had them since 2011.    http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/stereo/news/entire-sun.html    You don't need "L3" to have 360 view, you only need 2 satellites, one on each side.

Comment: One of the Stereo spacecraft moves a little faster than earth around the sun, the other slower. Only for a very brief time were they 180º apart. Here is their position now: http://stereo-ssc.nascom.nasa.gov/where.shtml. After awhile they will both be back on our side of the sun. For constant surveillance with little station keeping, L3 would be the best place from which to watch the far side of the sun. But an L3 sat would need relay sats, possibly at L4 and L5.

Comment: HopDavid, If we use two STEREO and some near-earth satellite, we will have 360 coverage of sun for longer time.

Comment: @osgx We do have two STEREO sats. Both are on the other side of the sun at the moment and as far as I know we don't have communication with them. Eventually they will both be near the earth again. For constant surveillance of the far side, L3 would be the location that needs the least station keeping.

Comment: "Solar weather observations? Nope, by definition we are interested in solar events going our way, not in the opposite direction."

As someone with an avid interest in Solar physics and space weather, I can assure you that this is not true at all; we'd very much love more data from the opposite limb, and frequently pull our hair out when events occur on the far side that we get little to zero data about.

Answer (score 0):

Currently NASA has two satellites flying in Solar conjunction with Earth, *near* the L3 point of Sun-Earth - STEREO A and STEREO B. They will not stop at L3, and the distance to L3 may be rather great. Current position ("Where is STEREO Today?"):
http://stereo.gsfc.nasa.gov/where.shtml

Some information about mission: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STEREO

STEREO is the mission to observe Sun from two additional angles. One satellite was started in 2006 to orbit, lower than Earth, and other - to higher orbit. One is "ahead" (A) of Earth and other is  "behind" (B) of Earth with the angle Satellite - Sun - Earth increasing at rate 21.650 degrees per year for A and decreasing at rate -22 degrees/year for B.

> they passed through Earth's Lagrangian points L4 and L5, in late 2009

In 2015 both STEREO satellites are behind Sun - http://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/stereo-entering-new-stage-of-operations/:

- "A" - from March 24 to July 7, 2015
- "B" - from Jan. 22 to March 23, 2015

In 2009 they where two artificial satellites made closest pass near L4 and L5 - http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/stereo/news/gravity_parking.html

> It will take several months for STEREO to pass through them, with
>   STEREO A making its closest pass to L4 in September, and STEREO B
>   making its closest pass to L5 in October.

Comment: The question is clearly about L3 (only).

Answer (score 0):

In time, all three (ES L3, L4, and L5) are likely to become viable locations for stationary, halo, or lissajous orbital satellites, largely in part to our current desires to place humans on mars and to mine the asteroid belt. As we all know, Earth and Mars are not synchronized space swimmers, so having distant communication devices that would enable continued contact for the 1-way adventurers to mars would prove evermore compelling.  Eventually (100s of years from now), space stations placed at L3, L4, and L5 should also be of interest when considering where to accumulate mined asteroid ores, with possibilities of refineries in those locations as well.  All this with the distant future in mind, of course (and nothing any of us will ever see, unless cryogenic freezing becomes a thing hahahahaha).

Comment: L3 is not an advantage for communications, as any comms with it from Earth will *have* to go through an intermediary already. Or pass through the core of the sun! With a relay on Earth and at L4 and/or L5, you have 100% coverage of the solar system already, with constant predictable comms pathways. L3 would not add to this, but just be a dependent itself.

Comment: The question is about L3. This answer hasn't provided any evidence or even educated guesses why L3 offer any particular advantage, to support planetary explorations, asteroids mining or any future space explorations. Just (unsubstantiated) opinions.